Store User Login and Logout timestamp
I have a requirement where I want to store when a user logins and logouts.
The catch is

if one session is active I should not be allowed to login into another session.
Logout should also be captured from browser close and session timeout

The solution I implemented is created a custom object to store session data. Used login flow to show message if record has another session as active.
Using LogoutEventStream I am populating logout time and status as closed for the record.
The issue is how do I capture browser close and populate it on the custom record.Or any other approach also helps

There is no way in Salesforce to detect browser close events in the standard UI.  You might be able to use Javascript beforeunload to detect closure within a custom Lighting Web Component, but even if that does work, it doesn't seem possible to put this LWC on every possible Salesforce page the user could access.
